# Java AWT Component and Panel Padding/Border

Tags: java, applet, panel, border, padding

I have no idea why I can't find a solution for this...  I am trying to layout some AWT components in a flow layout.  The only problem is the 'padding' between the components (Panels) when using a flow layout.  This is what the applet currently looks like:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KZgD.png

I need a way to set the Applet/Panels so that the two panels (black boxes) are touching (no 'padding').  The entire program is Swing free, all AWT, and I plan on keeping it that way.  I feel this is a very simple solution, but I have not been able to find an answer.

This is the init() code from the applet class:

```
public void init() {
  setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  c1 = new TestPanel();
  c2 = new TestPanel();
  c1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
  c2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 480));
  add(c1);
  add(c2);
}
```

This is the TestPanel class I'm using:

```
public class TestPanel extends Panel {
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getPreferredSize().width, this.getPreferredSize().height);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default horizontal (and vertical) gap of `FlowLayout` is set to `5`. Therefore, you must *explicitly* set the horizontal gap to `0`.

***FIRST APPROACH***

Invoke [`setHgap(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html#setHgap%28int%29) on the component's layout. Since the default layout of a `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`, simply do the following:

```
((FlowLayout)getLayout()).setHgap(0);
```

***SECOND APPROACH***

Use another `FlowLayout` constructor. That is, [`FlowLayout(int align, int hgap, int vgap)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html#FlowLayout%28int,%20int,%20int%29). And simply do the following:

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 5));
```